# Can we modelize an RNN by an ANN that takes precedent output as a part of input?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks

Is it possible to consider an RNN as a classical feedforward neural network that just take the precedent output as a part of the input ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost. I think that to match the [common interpretation of an RNN](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html) you need to **also** have a new input at each time-step (whereas you used the word "**just**" suggesting otherwise).

What you're describing is some function $f_1: \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$ whereas the "conventional" RNN is more like $f_2: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{R}^m$ refers to the **new** information at each time step.

Of course, this is all an exercise in interpreting semantics. So the other answer to your question is: "if you want it to"